# Saving files as CSV using VBA - currently saving multiple files as worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, csv

My original problem was finding out how to separate a file with 12000 rows into individual files with 1000 rows and keep the header. I found a great Q&A that does just that (with only one adjustment to number of rows), the link is here: [How to split spreadsheet into multiple spreadsheets with set number of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997851/how-to-split-spreadsheet-into-multiple-spreadsheets-with-set-number-of-rows?answertab=active#tab-top)

The only thing I need is for the script to save the files down as CSVs rather than Worksheets, but I can't see anything obvious in the script that defines the file type for me to change. FYI, I'm *very* new to this!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up [SaveAs() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx) of the `Workbook` object. See the `FileFormat` parameter and [xlFileFormat Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @vba4all in the comments above, the expression for `Workbook.SaveAs` is

`expression .SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)`

You can visit [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to read more about it.

To save the workbook as csv, you have to use

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

Please note that when you save the workbook as a csv with or without code, Excel will prompt you for confirmation. To avoid that you can set `Application.DisplayAlerts` to `False`

Here is an example

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

To read more about file formats, you may want to see [this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.15%29.aspx) link

Comment: bit unfair, he said he was very new to this and so was giving him the direct code sample.

Comment: also, his question states "the only thing he needs is to save the files down as CSV" he stated a solution for the 12k rows in his question!?

Comment: Point taken. Removed that part from the comment.  - 1 for an attempt to harvest points on someone else's suggestion :) Your direct code sample is not doing a better job than the msdn example. It is giving the code in a platter without even explaining what the code actually does.

Comment: If you would have posted that line of code before @vba4all, I wouldn't have downvoted you :)

Comment: fair do's...don't think it needs much explaining though ;-)

Comment: I hate downvoting but am really disappointed when I see this. Ok Guess what? Improve your answer and I will reverse the downvote. What say? I will even upvote it :)

Comment: You can revert the changes that I did if you are not happy about it