# How do I make this Excel macro save in .xls (Excel 97-2003) format, instead of .xlsx?

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is pretty close to exactly what I need:
[How to split spreadsheet into multiple spreadsheets with set number of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997851/how-to-split-spreadsheet-into-multiple-spreadsheets-with-set-number-of-rows/18001183#18001183)

It splits a long Excel file into smaller files based on number of rows.

HOWEVER, I need to modify it to save the files as .xls (Excel 97-2003) format.

What do I need to change?

Here's what I'm working with right now:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim RangeOfHeader As Range        'data (range) of header row
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile                    'how many rows (incl. header) in new files?

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Initialize data
  Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1
  RowsInFile = 100                   'as your example, just 10 rows per file

  'Copy the data of the first row (header)
  Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))

  For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    'Paste the header row in new file
    RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    'Paste the chunk of rows for this file
    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
    RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

    'Save the new workbook, and close it
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\splitoutput" & WorkbookCounter
    wb.Close

    'Increment file counter
    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
  Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) and [`XlFileFormat` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) documentation should give you what you need.

Comment: I see where I can get variable for FileFormat in both vaue and number format. I'm having trouble getting them inserted into the macro without breaking it.

Comment: Actually, I think that worked. I just changed this:

    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\splitoutput" & WorkbookCounter

to this:

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\splitoutput" & WorkbookCounter, _
        FileFormat:=xlExcel8

and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) and [`xlFileFormat` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) documentation are helpful here.

Change

```
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\splitoutput" & WorkbookCounter
```

to

```
wb.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\splitoutput" & WorkbookCounter, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```