# Split XLSX into multiple file by number of line in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I go through the this link

[How to split spreadsheet into multiple spreadsheets with set number of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997851/how-to-split-spreadsheet-into-multiple-spreadsheets-with-set-number-of-rows)

But I have few queries how to set base file path and how to call this function. I am new to ubuntu so please help me

Comment: Well for a start you don't do it from Ubuntu. The answers in the question you link to use Visual Basic which _is run from inside MS Office_.

Comment: @DavidW But my requirement is do it in ubuntu

Comment: Then I don't think the answers in the question you linked will help you at all

Comment: @DavidW Could you please help me. My requirement is to process xlsx file which may have more than 3 Million record  that why I want to break it so that I can process it in small chunks

Comment: I don't know the answer, sorry.